# Hashing - M should be a power of two

Tags: hash, knuth

I have heard that m should be a power of two in knuth multiplicative hash. Otherwise, a power of two is always a good choice. Could somebody please tell me in an easy way why this is more efficient?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For context, the general form of the Knuth multiplicative hash is this:

[image: hash formula]

If w = 2<sup>32</sup> and M is 2<sup>bits</sup>, then this simplifies to

```
h(K) = A * K >> (32 - bits)
```

Which is obviously really nice. The trick is to leave the division by w for later, use `mod w` (which is automatic), then extract from the *top* however many bits we would have gotten out if it was done the normal way (this corresponds to the division by w, scaling back by M, and doing the floor - all at once).

But that trick relies on w and M being powers of two. If M is not a power of two, there would be an other fixed-point multiplication (instead of just a right shift) to map the intermediary result from
[0 .. 2<sup>32</sup>-1] into [0 .. M-1], and since M would not divide 2<sup>32</sup> that would also introduce a bias into the distribution.

Comment: So the reason for the improvement of the efficiency is, that this trick enables shifting, which is faster for the calculation of the hashes?